# How did they calculate the output volume for this convnet example in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning, caffe

In this [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb), the output volumes are stated in output [25], and the receptive fields are specified in output [26].

Okay, the input volume `[3, 227, 227]` gets convolved with the region of size `[3, 11, 11]`.

Using this [formula](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) **`(W−F+2P)/S+1`**, where:
*`W` = the input volume size*
*`F` = the receptive field size*
*`P` = padding*
*`S` = stride*

...results with  `(227 - 11)/4 + 1 = 55` i.e. **[55*55*96]**. So far so good :)

For 'pool1' they used `F=3`and `S=2` I think? The calculation checks out: `55-3/2+1=27`.

From this point I get a bit confused. The receptive field for the second convnet layer is `[48, 5, 5]`, yet the output for 'conv2' is equal to `[256, 27, 27]`. What calculation happened here?

And then, the height and width of the output volumes of 'conv3' to 'conv4' are all the same `[13, 13]`? What's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at the [parameters of `conv2` layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt#L55) you'll notice

```
   pad: 2
```

That is, the input blob is padded by 2 extra pixels all around, thus the formula now is

```
27 + 2 + 2 - ( 5 - 1 ) = 27
```

Padding a kernel size of `5` with `2` pixels from both sides yields the same output size.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, so is this calculation also valid: `(27 - 5 + 2*2)/1 + 1 = 27`. Also, just one more question. How come the depth of the 'conv2' is 48? Isn't the depth supposed to be equal to the number of kernels applied in the previous layer? Again, many thanks for your time.

Comment: @apples-oranges I believe so

Comment: Ok great, I think I understand it now.